# How about a simple graphics tool?

Tags: feature-request

How about including a simple drawing tool in the answer section. I was faced with answering a question about cmos transistor layout today. I needed to produce some graphics for this. This was as simple as a few rectangles and some text annotations.

So instead of using an integrated tool I had to go to my graphics editor of choice. Save the results and then crop them to fit the images in the answer section and then upload them.

This was time consuming and cumbersome at best. If I was not in a position where I have some time available at present I would not have bothered to answer the question.

Comment: Are there any that are free and useful? I think this is a good idea but I've yet to see a single feature besides the circuit tool actually get implemented by SE for a single site

Comment: We don't even have a special character drop-down for special characters (mu, omega, degrees, etc.).

Comment: Also, you can copy directly into questions now to avoid the upload

Comment: @Voltage Spike Thanks for that information I will try that.

Comment: I could make an argument that the schematic tool that is available in questions and answers can do reasonably good graphics. I could also make an argument to suggest that anyone not making use of free circuit diagram tools (aka free simulators) for doing schematics, should be advised to do so in an attempt to convert the bodger up to half-decent hobbyist level. It's just not acceptable these days to see illegible hand drawn scrawls as schematics.